# How to get the path of one video that I picked by Intent in Android Studio using its Uri?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-file, realpath

I want to use the path to copy that video to another directory but the error that throws me says my URI or path does not exist.

```
   probar.setOnClickListener({
        val selectedImageUri2=globalVariable.video//here I just saved the uri path of the intent
        if(!CheckPermissionFromDevice()){
            requestPermission()
        } else {
            val sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath +"/"+ selectedImageUri2.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "SOURCE PATH:: "+sourcePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("SOURCE"+sourcePath)
            val source= File(sourcePath)
            val destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/AudioFiscalia/"
            val destination = File(destinationPath)
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "TRY BIEN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "CATCH"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                println("error"+e.toString())
            }
        }
    })
```

This is my error: 
Source '/storage/emulated/0/content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FHDCamera%2FVID_20190903_114707.mp4' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the path of one video that I picked by Intent in Android Studio using its Uri?

You don't.

The user does not have to choose a file on the filesystem. The user could choose content in cloud storage, on a file server, etc.

Even if the user does elect to choose some local content, you may not have access to it. On Android 10+, you have very little filesystem access. And, even on Android 9 and older devices, the user could choose:

- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- ...and so on

You do not have access to any of that via the filesystem.

> I want to use the path to copy that video to another directory

Preferably, do not do that. Beyond your problems with the source location, your destination is inaccessible to you on Android 10.

If you switch your destination to some location that you *can* use, you can get an `InputStream` on the source by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` that you got.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I actually needed that clarification. In case I needed to change the location of my videos... How could I use the InputStream? I hope you can help me.

Comment: @Emmanuel: "How could I use the InputStream?" -- read bytes from the `InputStream` and write them to some `OutputStream`, for example.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/VID_20190903_114707.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) it gives me this error. More of the same (thanks for replying)

Comment: @Emmanuel: Perhaps you do not have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (in the manifest and requested at runtime). Or perhaps that file does not exist. And, as I have noted, you have no access to that location on Android 10+ anyway.